# How to generate tables in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to generate tables like 'test_table_1', 'test_table_2'... What I am doing wrong?

```html
declare @i int = 1;
declare @i_str varchar(1024);
declare @table VARCHAR(1024);


while (@i < 500)
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1;
SET @table = 'TEST_TABLE_' + convert(varchar, @i);

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = @table) 

CREATE TABLE @table (
 ID INT,
 userid INT,
 name TEXT,
 last_name TEXT,
 country TEXT,
 city TEXT
)

END
```

Error: 
Incorrect syntax near @table. Expecting '.', ID or QUOTED_ID

Comment: first of all don't initialize in this way    declare @i int = 1;   make it declare @i int, and set @i =1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that a temp table uses a hash #table. you are trying to pass the name as a variable.

One way you can try to achive that is to build a create table string

```
declare @createTable varchar(1000),
    @table varchar(30) = 'table1'
SET @createTable = 'CREATE TABLE #' + @table + ' (ID INT,userid INT,    name TEXT,last_name TEXT,country TEXT,city TEXT)'

EXEC (@createTable)
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but i wanted simple tables, not temporary. Thank you.

Comment: Understood, just remove the hash. Should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create permanent tables (not Temporary tables) then one of the option is use of Dynamic query. like shown below

```
 DECLARE  @TableName NVARCHAR(128) DECLARE @Column1Name NVARCHAR(32)
 DECLARE @Column1DataType NVARCHAR(32) DECLARE @Column1Nullable NVARCHAR(32)

 DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '( '+ @Column1Name + '
 ' + @Column1DataType + ' '+ @Column1Nullable +')  ' 
EXEC (@SQLString)
```